# Splitting sentences in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to split words, punctuation, numbers from a sentence. However, my code produces output that isn't expected. How can I fix it?

This is my input text (in a text file):

```
 "I 2changed to ask then, said that mildes't of men2,
```

And my code outputs this:

```
['"', 'I', '2', 'changed', 'to', 'ask', 'then', ',', 'said', 'that', "mildes't", 'of', 'men2']
```

However, the expected output is:

```
 ['"', 'I', '2', 'changed', 'to', 'ask', 'then', ',', 'said', 'that', "mildes't", 'of', 'men','2']
```

Here's my code:

```
import re
newlist = []
f = open("Inputfile2.txt",'r')
out = f.readlines()
for line in out:
    word = line.strip('\n')
    f.close()
    lst = re.compile(r"\d|\w+[\w']+|\w|[^\w\s]").findall(word)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Looks like homework...

Comment: please move the f.close() outside the loop... or even better use with open("Inputfile2.txt",'r') as f:

Comment: Also, you don't need to re.compile the regex on every loop iteration. Just call re.findall("myregex", word) and it will be implicitly compiled the first time, then reused on subsequent iterations. You code will run much more quickly

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions, '\w' matches any alphanumeric character, i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9].

Also in the first part of your regular expression, it should be '\d+' to match more than one digits.

The second and the third part of your regular expression '\w+[\w']+|\w' can be merged into a single part by changing '+' to '*'.

```
import re
with open('Inputfile2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip('\n')
        lst = re.compile(r"\d+|[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z']*|[^\w\s]").findall(word)
        print(lst)
```

This gives:

```
['"', 'I', '2', 'changed', 'to', 'ask', 'then', ',', 'said', 'that', "mildes't", 'of', 'men', '2', ',']
```

Note that your expected output is incorrect. It is missing a ','.